# Resizing images: how to select BOTH the image and its container?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I find it incredibly laborious, in order to resize images, to first reduce the size of the image, and then reduce the size of its container. Is there not a way to select both image and container and change their sizes at the same time?

Comment: Check what scaling option is selected in the Transform panel dropdown menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the image and container by clicking inside the image area, but outside that center circular section.

Command(CTRL)+SHIFT and grab a corner handle to resize both the image and the container at the same time.

Double-clicking on one of the container handles will also shrink the container to fit what's inside it, anchored to the container in the opposite corner or side (this works on corner or center edge handles. It also works on text frames.)